# Handling executing processes

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, process

A couple of days ago I began to get an error with a c# winform application I've been creating stating that

> The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x278f58 to COM context 0x2790c8 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment 
>   is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages.

This is occuring when I am using a separate thread to run exe processes to avoid freezing up the ui. In a release version, this program runs fine and as expected but pretty much makes it impossible to consistently debug my program (sometimes works fine, others not so fine)..

I've tried implementing this process by forcing a `BackgroundWorker` to be synchronous using multiple googled answers which solves the issue of this error but makes my program work in unexpected ways (textboxes populated before exe finished resulting in erroneous data).

I have read that this error will only occur in production and not in a release.. so my question is should I just try to live with this annoyance or is their a non backgroundworker solution? If any code example is needed I can provide but I don't believe it is necessary

Comment: It is a debugger warning.  You won't get it without a debugger.  Although there is definitely some likelihood that you'll get the *exact* same complaint from your users.  They won't quite understand why your UI freezes or why the program can't be stopped and won't respond to input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Managed Debugging Assistant (MDA) is telling you that a single-threaded apartment (STA) COM thread hasn't responded to a message in 60 seconds. STA COM is done through message passing. This exception occurs if MDA is switched on, which it is by default when running under a debugger. The MDA works to detect deadlock with a pre-defined timeout, and it's only effective when you're running the program under the VS debugger.

Since many COM components are STA and the main thread in Windows Forms is also STA, this is a warning that you’re blocking. This is probably occurring because you are stalling the message loop by spending time stepping through code.

To switch this off for a single project, add the following content to your application configuration file:

```
<mdaConfig> 
  <assistants> 
    <contextSwitchDeadlock enable="false" /> 
  </assistants> 
</mdaConfig>
```

To switch this off globally:

- Click on the *Debug* menu in Visual Studio.
- Choose the Exceptions option (*Debug -> Exceptions*).
- The Exceptions window will open.
- Expand the "*Managed Debugging Assistants*" node.
- Uncheck the **ContextSwitchDeadlock** option under the *Thrown* column.
- Click OK and close the Exceptions window.

The implication of disabling this MDA is that you lose a useful tool for discovering bugs before you release the application. Of course if you see this deadlock when not running under the debugger then you need to do a normal deadlock analysis.

Comment: Thanks for this useful insight.. I think for my particular case I'm going to just work around this as much as possible, I've minimized the risk of an actual deadlock as much as possible for now..